# Retrieve/Update Custom Object using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, form, sales-cloud

I am attempting to update a custom object on Sales Cloud through a Marketing Cloud landing page. I am not using MC send, the email comes from Sales Cloud and lands on an MC page, then the form queries info from URL. The page renders perfectly fine when the user clicks the link.

**ISSUE: Whenever the form is submitted, the webpage crashes - 500 - Internal server error.**

```
%%[

SET @Id = QueryParameter('lcid')
SET @lcnm = QueryParameter('lcnm')

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

    /* get location id */

  SET @locationRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Locations__c",
   "Id",
   "Id", "=", @Id
   )

  IF RowCount(@locationRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @result = Field(Row(@locationRows, 1), "Id")

      /* update location */

SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Location__c", @Id,
      "Website_Host_Name__c", RequestParameter("webhost"),
      "Username_for_Your_Website__c", RequestParameter("username"),
      "Password_for_Your_Website__c", RequestParameter("pswd")
     ) 

     ENDIF
]%% 

<h2><center>We Got It! We will connect your website to Software in a jiffy!</center>
</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%
<div class="form-style-5">
  <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
<h1>
 <center>%%=V(@lcnm)=%%'s Website Log-in Details</center>
            </h1>
            <label>Website Host Name: </label>
            <p style="font-size:70%;">The URL where you make changes to your website (like www.godaddy.com or www.wix.com) or the IP address if you use FTP format for your login credentails. We need full access so we can insert the line of code.
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="webhost" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Username for Your Website: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Password for Your Website:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pswd" required="">
            <br>
            <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="TRUE">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  %%[endif]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` and `Field` functions.

Once you've provided the name of your object on the first parameter of the function, there is no need to prefix the other columns names with it. Try this:

```
SET @locationRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Locations__c",
   "Id",
   "Id", "=", @Id
   )
```

The same thing applies to Field function, no need to add your object's api name before each column name. Try this instead:

```
 SET @result = Field(Row(@locationRows, 1), "Id")
```

The final code should look like:

```
%%[
set @Id = QueryParameter(lcid)

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

    /* get location id */

  SET @locationRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Locations__c",
   "Id",
   "Id", "=", @Id
   )

  IF RowCount(@locationRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @result = Field(Row(@locationRows, 1), "Id")

      /* update location */

SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Location__c", @Id,
      "Website_Host_Name__c", RequestParameter("webhost"),
      "Username_for_Your_Website__c", RequestParameter("username"),
      "Password_for_Your_Website__c", RequestParameter("pswd")
     ) 

     ENDIF
]%% 
<h2><center>We Got It! We will connect your Website to *Company* in a Jiffy!</center>
</h2>
%%[ ELSE ]%%
<div class="form-style-5">
  <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>

            <label>Website Host Name: </label>
            <p style="font-size:70%;">The URL where you make changes to your website (like www.godaddy.com or www.wix.com) or the IP address if you use FTP format for your login credentails. We need full access so we can insert the line of code.
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="webhost" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Username for Your Website: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Password for Your Website:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pswd" required="">
            <br>
            <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="TRUE">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  %%[endif]%%
```